# Application bound to port but server not listening - WebSphere Application Server - Commerce App

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce

So we have a staging server running commerce that's binding to port 8000:

[12/23/15 15:21:44:043 EST] 0000000f webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module WorkspaceAdministration has been bound to VH_comm_Tools[xxx.xxx.com:8000,*:8000]

The issue here is I can't connect to that port and netstat -an | grep 8000 shows it's not listening.    telnet or curling the locahost does not return anything.  Iptables is also disabled.

I have another environment that's working without adding a port in the HTTP Transport chain although i did attempt that but without any luck.

Can someone chime in please??

Thank you!

WAS ND 8.5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

The message you included is referring to the "host aliases" defined in the "virtual host" the .war is associated with.  These are accessible via the WAS admin console.

Separately, your web container is associated with a TCP transport listening on one or more ports.  These are accessible in the WAS admin console in a slightly different area.

The server will let you create host aliases that do not match any listening port, because they could be logical ports used by frontend proxy/http servers.

I'd suggest you do one of two things:

figure out your listening ports, then add them as host aliases to the virtual host your app is associated with
or
find a virtual host with host aliases that match your listening ports and associate your web module with that virtual host instead.